# Nativescript 5 Can not build new app on local machine

Tags: nativescript

Im trying to create a new Nativescript app (with angular), and always getting this error when building on local machine.

I've tested in two diferents machines with the same behavior. If I try to build on the cloud I can execute fine without problems.

In other side, I have an older app with 4.1 version and I can build on local and execute in the emulator without problems.

```
System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xfffffff6
System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getAnimation(Resources.java:1189)
System.err:     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:75)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation(FragmentManager.java:1102)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1600)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:725)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.testns (pid 14123) has died
```

EDIT:
Finally I could execute the app. I uninstalled the nativescript npm package and installed again.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue with default template, so would you mind sharing a sample project where we can see the issue.

Comment: It's an empty project and it happens with any of the angular templates. Currently I have just created an app with the drawer navigation template and only runs If I build the app with sidekick on the cloud.

Comment: Sadly that sounds like your environment issue. I'm able to build apps locally with 5.x CLI and Runtime. Make sure you have latest support libraries and Android 28 installed, you may verifiy them from Android Studio.

Comment: New projects with 5.0 don't work for me either. I just returned to 4.2 by changing everything tns-android, tns-ios, and tns-core-modules to 4.2.0 and new projects build just fine.

Comment: Hello, I have exactly the same problem. I tried to reinstall nativescript package and it doesn't helped. What exactly you did please?

Comment: I removed the package from global "npm uninstall -g nativescript" and then installed again.